# Find if a string is not part of a list of list in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists (List):

```
[[abc-kr, 0, 4, -0.031]
[kkg-kg, 0, 6, -0.03]
[art-m, 1, 20, 0.036]
[abc-kg, 0, 4, -0.023]]
```

I want to make another list and remove lists if the first part of first item is the same, so only either first or last list in List should be a part of the new list. it would be better if the item containing the lower value would remain on list 2.

As a starting point I have been trying to do it this way:

```
finalList = []
for line in List:
item = line.split("-")
if item[0] not in finalList:
    finalList.append(line)
```

I thought this should work but it does not, so I was thinking if someone could point me into a right direction?

Comment: Are you aware that the leftmost values are differences of pairs of variables, not variables?

Comment: The element are all strings, even the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to maintain a separate array with the 'first parts' of each item, to which the first part of an item would be added only if it doesn't already belong to that array, and have the check be against this array of first parts, rather than against finalList. In other words,

```
finalList = []
firstParts = []
for line in List:
    item = line[0].split("-")
    print item[0]
    if item[0] not in firstParts:
            firstParts.append(item[0])
            finalList.append(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
data = [['abc-kr', 0, 4, -0.031],
['kkg-kg', 0, 6, -0.03],
['art-m', 1, 20, 0.036],
['abc-kg', 0, 4, -0.023]]

new_data = {el[0].partition('-')[0]:el for el in data}.values()
```